# How to "add REST API Reference" in a VB.net class library in VS2017? the right-click option doesn't appear

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, client

I'm trying to add a REST API reference to a vb.net class library application. The option that I'm used to do ("right-click--> Add--> Rest API Client") simply doesn't appear on vb.net class libraries.
How can I do that?

I expect to be able to consume a REST API from my vb.net code without having to write all the references by hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["REST API Client" option in Visual Studio for ASP.NET Core projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864287/rest-api-client-option-in-visual-studio-for-asp-net-core-projects)

Comment: I took a look at the "possible duplicate" question and it's not the same issue I ran into. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Didn't find a way to use the **shortcut** "right-click--> Add--> Rest API Client" in VS2017 when dealing w/ VB.Net class library/ Windows Form projects types.

The solution was to **add a C# class library project**,  to be able to add the Rest API reference via Project's context menu. Then **it was just to reference** the n**ew created C# project** (containing the API ref) **in the main Project (VB.Net).**